# Assert function to compare strings returned by 2 different methods in c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, nunit, assertions

I have 2 methods in c# selenium framework. I am using Nunit framework for testing

```
public String method1()

{

String s  = "This is example 1";

return s

}

public string method2()

{

String s = "example 2";

return s;

}
```

I need to check that both strings contain, the same, specific text 'Example'. Is there an 'Assert' function to compare?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check that both strings contain, the same, specific text?

Comment: @Josh yes, That's right

Comment: So not just that the strings are equal?

Comment: yes. Need to make sure method 1 always returns a string with text example which is returned by method 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've responded with, it sounds like you just need to use:

```
string one = method1();
string two = method2();
StringAssert.Contains(two, one);
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. But I don't want to hard code "example". Example will be returned by another method

Comment: Updated my answer for you.